# NTP - ntpq -c peers showing incorrect stratum for peers

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, ntp

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 as an Amazon Web Services instance. 
When I run **ntpq -c peers** on my server I get the following output:

```
# ntpq -c peers
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 time-a.nist.gov .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 time-b.nist.gov .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

I read this to state that the 2 servers in the response are stratum 16 servers which I know to be incorrect (the nist.gov servers are stratum 1). I know there is a connection to the NIST servers because ntpdate -d time-a.nist.gov connects and shows offset fine.

What causes the stratum to be displayed incorrectly, and what can I do to make sure the command shows the correct stratum?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refid .INIT. and stratum 16 indicates that you are not getting any responses from those servers.  Check your firewall(s).

Comment: If ntpq is not getting through the firewall then why does ntpdate -d time.nist.gov give me information?

Answer (score 2):

As already noted stratum 16 servers are unreachable.  Therefore, they have no usable time information.   As soon as you successfully connect to a server is stratum will be reported.  It takes several time exchanges before `ntp` will consider using time from the server.

`ntpdate -d` uses a non-privileged outgoing port, while `ntp` will use port 123 as source and destination.  It is possible to block either with firewall rules.  If you don't allow `established` connections before you block incoming traffic to port 123, `ntp` will fail.

It is common to have a `cstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED` firewall rule at the top of a chain which accepts traffic.  This simplifies the rule set as return traffic does not have be dealt with specific rules.